# How do i change the number format of an integer in a dataframe?

Tags: python, number-formatting

I have imported data from a CSV file into a dataframe. One of the columns is a reference number and should have six digits. Some of the reference numbers have only 3, 4 or 5 digits. Is there a similar function that exists in Excel which would something like `this: =TEXT(A1,"000000")`?

I've tried searching on the internet for some documentation on how to use the format and display functions in pandas but i couldn't find the answer that i was looking for. An example of the issue is shown below:

```
Actual: 10158
Desired: 010158

Actual: 101
Desired: 010100
```

Comment: Seriously? 101 is equivalent to 10100? Don't you want 000101?

Comment: Yes, seriously. They are trade codes and sometimes the digits omitted are at the start and end of the number. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity: If there are two same numbers in the desired format: 010100 and 010100.. How would you tell if they both are 101, or one is 101 and the other is 1010, or both are 1010, or both are 10100 in actual values?

Comment: In Excel i can visually tell because of the order of the reference numbers. So i would already know that 010100 has appeared above and that it is now the latter sequence of numbers so can adjust the formula to account for this. Not a particularly fun dataset to work with.

Answer (score 0):

try to read it directly in the right format with this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv", dtype = {"ColumnName" : "float64"})
```

probably its already a string.

You can always check your types of a dataframe with `df.dtypes`

Comment: The link above has provided part of the solution so I'll explore that. Thanks for your help.